# Asteroids Game in Visual Basic Assistance

Tags: vb.net

I am currently doing Advanced Higher Computer Science and I have chosen to make Asteroids for my project. I have only just started, but here is my code so far:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyData = Keys.D OrElse e.KeyData = Keys.Right Then
        Spaceship.Left += 3
    End If

    If e.KeyData = Keys.A OrElse e.KeyData = Keys.Left Then
        Spaceship.Left -= 3
    End If

    If e.KeyData = Keys.W OrElse e.KeyData = Keys.Up Then
        Spaceship.Top -= 3
    End If

    If e.KeyData = Keys.S OrElse e.KeyData = Keys.Down Then
        Spaceship.Top += 3
    End If
    Refresh()

    If e.KeyData = Keys.Space Then
        ' generate a bullet which continues in a straight line until it hits something
    End If

    If e.KeyData = Keys.Escape Then
        End
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, I have allowed the user to close the form and move the spaceship with arrow keys. However, I require help on the following:

- Allow the user to shoot bullets using spacebar
- If spaceship goes off one side of screen, then go back on at other side (I have an idea for this, so this is not necessary)
- Move asteroids around randomly, not teleport, which I can already do. I have started to attempt this, so just ask if you want to see it.

That's all folks, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to point out, that control scheme is incorrect if you're trying to replicate asteroids fully. Left/A and Right/D do the orientation of your ship, not move left/right and Up/W moves you forward. There is no Down/S control

Comment: Stack Overflow is not to be considered a coding service. We're here to help with **specific** programming related problems. Please take a moment to read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).